# Connection getting undefined while trying to implement connection pool in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to implement a connection pooling in node.js. In `getConnection()` method, if my pool is empty, I am creating one with given number of connections.
When control comes to `var connection = pool[last]`, it gives me `pool is undefined`. Can someone help me out. Thanks

```
pool = null;
last = 0;
function connectionPool(connectionsNumber) {
  pool = [];
  for (var i=0; i < connectionsNumber; ++i) {
    pool.push(mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'Rileysteele1',
        dateStrings : true,
        database : 'twitter',
        port     : 3306
    }));
  }
}

function getConnection() {
  if (!pool) {
    initializeConnection(40);
  }
  var connection = pool[last];
  last++;
  if (last == pool.length)
    last = 0;
  return connection;
}

function initializeConnection() {
  pool = new connectionPool(2);
}

exports.initializeConnection = initializeConnection;
exports.getConnection = getConnection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's because `connectionPool()` is being treated as a constructor (with `new`) but it's not really a constructor and is actually setting `pool` internally.

Remove the `pool = new` portion and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`node-mysql` supports [connection pooling out of the box](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections). It seems overkill to implement it yourself.